# Unable to align my sidebar to the contents section instead of comments

Tags: css

Relevant link: http://themeforward.com/demo2/2011/01/17/testing-comments/

I've been toying with this for about 10 minutes, trying to get the sidebar to align properly and I can't figure it out.

I placed my comments in a new DIV to separate them from the posts.  Usually I wouldn't do this but I want designers to have full CSS control without adding new classes when they start using this theme to build.

**Anyway, my sidebar ends up being aligned with my comments rather than the content on my page.**

Moving the div under the endif is not an option here because I want to be able to style just the post by itself if desired.  Putting the comments below the sidebar makes the comments disappear!

My code looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="container">
<div id="post_content">
<div class="clear">
<!-- Grab posts -->
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- Post title -->
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>


<div class="sub-title-post">
<?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link( ); ?>, under <?php the_category(', ') ?>
</div>

<!-- The post -->
<?php the_content(); ?>


<?php edit_post_link('Edit', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>

<!-- Tags -->
<h3 class="tags"><?php the_tags('Tags ',' / ','<br />'); ?></h3>
<h3 class="tags"><?php $turl = getTinyUrl(get_permalink($post->ID));
echo 'Short URL <a href="'.$turl.'">'.$turl.'</a>' ?></h3>

<!-- Next/Previous Posts -->
<div class="mp_archive2">
<div id="more_posts">
<div class="oe"><?php previous_post_link('%link', '-', TRUE); ?></div>
<div class="re"><?php next_post_link('%link', '+', TRUE); ?></div>
</div>
</div>




</div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>No matching entries found.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>


</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: close voted as plain css & html question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put content and comments into a container div with float: left; and then add the same to your sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS is all messed up, first you want to float the sidebar and any other containers **left**, second stop using !important when your not even overwriting anything, next the major problem is you using `clear:both:` all over the place.

move `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` above `<?php comments_template(); ?>` take out the unnecessary CSS and `float:left.`

Also consider using  `post_class`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class

Answer (score 0):

try styling the post content to float left, sidebar to float right, and clear left the comment.